# Angular typescript object.assign not working (it return error cannot read 'length' of null)

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, angular8, deep-copy

At File "a.ts", it will call handleRequests() of file "b.ts"

```
_alerts: Banner[];
obj = {};

postMessage() {
   this.obj[this._alerts[0].uuid] = this._alerts;
   const data = {
        'object': this.obj
   };
   this.service.handleRequests(stateAction);
}
postMessage();
```

At file "b.ts",

```
I would like to combine "data.object" with "this.object" and store the result at "this.object" variable. 

When initialize object to null, at run time it gives "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null"

object = null ;
handleRequests(data) {
   this.object = Object.assign({}, ...this.object, ...data.object);
}

If intialize object to {}, at compile time it gives error "type { } is not an array type."

object = {}
handleRequests(data) {
   this.object = Object.assign({}, ...this.object, ...data.object);
}
```

Is there some issues with the object initialization at "b.ts"?

Comment: The spread syntax (`...`) seems wrong in your `Object.assign` call. I didn't try it, but taking a look at the [MDN example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) it looks like you should just pass the object

Comment: I’m using the spread operator in ecmascript to combine the objects

Comment: Ive seen function that use both object.assign and spread operator at same line of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the spread operator (`...`) from your `Object.assign` call, like this:

```
object = null;
handleRequests(data) {
   this.object = Object.assign({}, this.object, data.object);
}
```

Alternatively, use the spread operator instead of `Object.assign`:

```
object = {};
handleRequests(data) {
   this.object = { ...this.object, ...data.object };
}
```

Those are two different ways of achieving the same effect. Choose one, not both.
Also note that you can't use the second method (spreading) on an object that is `null`.